# Excel VBA: Indicate to user progress of PivotCaches.create

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked around for a while but can't find an answer on this one. In my VBA I have a line that creates a new pivottable and inserts it into the worksheet like so-

```
Application.StatusBar = MyPC.RecordCount

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ACCESS2"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
   CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Dashboard!R20C1", TableName:= _
   "PTDashboard", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

Application.StatusBar = False
```

When I was in the early stages of building this the statusbar would display a counter of how many records it was bringing into the pivotCache from the Connection. It has gone for some reason and I am trying to emulate what it was doing (it might have been an Excel 2013 thing as I have been working on this project on the home computer aswell).

Because there could be a few hundred thousand records it can take up to a minute and I want some indication to the user that it is happening.

I usually do this within a loop but as I don't have that option I am a bit stumped. Is there somewhere in the background where I can read this data from? I hope I have been clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you add a `Application.DisplayStatusBar = True` at the beginning?

Comment: Hi BK201 I tried that just now and it doesn't change anything. The statusbar is on with the usual 'Ready','Calculate' and 'Record Macro' displayed. I'll try and screenshot it if I can replicate it on my laptop with 2013.

Comment: I have confirmed that Excel 2013 does what i want 2010 to do. Starting to think though that this may not be possible. Here is an image I took of what I am trying to do in Excel 2010. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BbPgqSqCUAAkUzP.jpg:large

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to access the data the way you want, but in order to avoid the appearance that your application is hanging or the code has stopped working, here is one thing you can do.

Create a small `UserForm`, and put one label on it with a message that indicates your macro is *doing something*, e.g., "Please wait while Pivotecache loads... this can take up to 1 minute."

Then, display it `vbModeless` immediately before you call your PivotCache, and unload it immediately after.

I tested this with a loop but I think it should work with what you are doing, too, something like:

```
Sub Test()

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ACCESS2"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Dashboard!R20C1", TableName:= _
        "PTDashboard", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

    Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Even I am not aware if there is a method to get the data realtime while the PivotCache is being created. Keeping the user informed is the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this?

```
Application.StatusBar = "Creating Pivot... Please be Patient"
DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ACCESS2"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Dashboard!R20C1", TableName:= _
"PTDashboard", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

Application.StatusBar = "Pivot Created!"
DoEvents
```

Comment: Hi Siddarth, thanks for the suggestion but it hasn't triggered the effect I am after. I managed to get a shot of what i am trying to do. Link below. I might have to concede on this. StatusBar = "wait a minute, go get a coffee, put your feet up" will just have to do https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BbPgqSqCUAAkUzP.jpg:large

Comment: It must be the case. I was hoping there might have been a technical way to do it and it wasn't just a feature only available from 13 and onwards. Ohwell, patience will just be the answer for now :)

Comment: I guess you will have to then stick to either with what I suggested or what david suggested :)